# My pdo read statment its not working correctly

Tags: php, pdo

Im trying to devellop a pagination system and Im having an strange issue.
I have this code below and the code is always entering in my if condition saying there are 0 results.
But I have the sql statment correct when I do a print_r.
Can you see if theres something wrong that I´m not seeing?

```
 $pag = (empty($_GET['pag']) ? '1' : $_GET['pag']);
            $max = 3;
            $begin = ($pag * $max) - $max;
            $readPages = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pages where id_numb IS null LIMIT :beg,:ma");  
            $readPages->bindValue(":beg", $begin);
            $readPages->bindValue(":ma", $max);    
            $readPages->execute();
            $num_rows = $readPages->rowCount();

            if(!$num_rows >= 1)
            {
                echo '0 results';
            }
```

Comment: do you have a records with null id_numb fields? Did you check that `$begin` is being correctly calculated?

Comment: what is your database? Mysql?

Answer (score 1):

1. [always enable exception mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858) for PDO to be notified of SQL errors
2. for the LIMIT clause you have to [set PDO::PARAM_INT explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15991623)

Answer (score 0):

```
        $num_rows = readPages->rowCount();
                    ^---missing $. A constant object? no way...
        print_r($lerCat);
                 ^^^^^^--- undefined variable
```

Comment: Thanks but thats no the problem, I put that wrong doing the translation!